# Супер-что-то))

Tags: стилистика

Сейчас модно в рекламе ко всему добавлять приставку "супер-". Но насколько это вообще грамотно? Например, какие-нибудь "суперцены" ("сверхцены", что ли?) или супермебель ("сверхмебель"??))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В "Словаре иностранных слов" СУПЕР  трактуется  в разных значениях, а не только "сверх". Есть значения "главный, высшего качества, свойства или повышенного усиленного действия", то есть лучший. Так что "суперцену" вполне можно рассматривать как "лучшая цена, привлекательная цена".